# WooCommerce email based on shipping zone

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I need send email instructions when customer select shipping `zone id = 0` (The rest of the world).

I found code below, but its based on payment method:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );

function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

  if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

    if ( 'cod' == $order->payment_method ) {
      // cash on delivery method
      echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> Full payment is due immediately upon delivery: <em>cash only, no exceptions</em>.</p>';
    } else {
      // other methods (ie credit card)
      echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> Please look for "Madrigal Electromotive GmbH" on your next credit card statement.</p>';
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change it to specific shipping zone please? 
How can I set specific email instructions based on shipping zone in WooCommerce?

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get the shipping zone for an order is not so easy. It can be done with the following code example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'custom_text_in_email_shipping_zone_based', 10, 4 );
function custom_text_in_email_shipping_zone_based( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

        // Get the shipping method related data (we need the Instance ID)
        $shipping_item        = $order->get_items('shipping');
        $item = reset($shipping_item);
        $shipping_method_id   = $item->get_method_id();
        $method_arr           = explode( ':', $shipping_method_id );

        // Get the Zone ID and related data
        $shipping_zone_object = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', $method_arr[1] );
        $zone_id              = $shipping_zone_object->get_id();        // Zone ID
        $zone_name            = $shipping_zone_object->get_zone_name(); // Zone name
        // Get the zone locations codes and types (if needed)
        foreach( $shipping_zone_object->get_zone_locations() as $zone_location ){
            $zone_location_code = $zone_location->code;
            $zone_location_type = $zone_location->type;
        }

        if ( '0' == $zone_id ) {
            // Rest of the world
            echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> for Rest of the world.</p>';
        }
        elseif ( 'Mexico' == $zone_name ) {
            // Mexico zone name
            echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> for Mexico.</p>';
        }
        else {
            // All other zones
            echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> Other zones.</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `WC_Abstract_Order` codex page https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_has_shipping_method you can check the shipping method using `has_shipping_method()`.

So, your if statement should be something like

```
if ( $order->has_shipping_method('name_of_my_shipping_method') ) {
```

I couldn't find an equivalent for shipping zones though.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'custom_text_in_email_shipping_zone_based', 10, 4 );
function custom_text_in_email_shipping_zone_based( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

```
    // Get the shipping method related data (we need the Instance ID)
    $shipping_item        = $order->get_items('shipping');
    $item = reset($shipping_item);
    $shipping_method_id   = $item->get_method_id();
    $method_arr           = explode( ':', $shipping_method_id );

    // Get the Zone ID and related data
    $shipping_zone_object = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', $method_arr[1] );
    $zone_id              = $shipping_zone_object->get_id();        // Zone ID
    $zone_name            = $shipping_zone_object->get_zone_name(); // Zone name
    // Get the zone locations codes and types (if needed)
    foreach( $shipping_zone_object->get_zone_locations() as $zone_location ){
        $zone_location_code = $zone_location->code;
        $zone_location_type = $zone_location->type;
    }

    if ( '0' == $zone_id ) {
        // Rest of the world
        echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> for Rest of the world.</p>';
    }
    elseif ( 'Mexico' == $zone_name ) {
        // Mexico zone name
        echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> for Mexico.</p>';
    }
    else {
        // All other zones
        echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> Other zones.</p>';
    }
}
```

}

The code showing above doesn't work even though the author has stated tried and tested, can anybody update the code.

No matter what zone you select you always end up with All other zones.