# Woocommerce Emails based on Shipping Zone and Product Category

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email, woocommerce

I have managed to get some code based on payment methods working *(taken from an existing answer code)* which is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );

function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

  if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

    if ( 'cod' == $order->payment_method ){
      // cash on delivery method
      echo '<p><strong>Please note: </strong>Your repair is currently pending acceptance from your local technician. A member of our team will contact you shortly.</p>';
  }
        elseif( $product_category == 'unlocking'){
        // unlocking email
        echo '<p>Your device should be unlocked within 48 hours, if your device requires an unlock code we will be in touch.</p>';
    }
      else {
      // other methods (ie credit card)
      echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> Please ensure your device is packaged securely and send it to the following address:</p><br><br><p><strong>Please note; if using our Unlocking service, you do NOT need to send us your device.</strong></p>';
    }
  }
}
```

Im making the assumption that my use of `$product_category` is incorrect and needs some reference. I tried using *"[WooCommerce email based on shipping zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303802/woocommerce-email-based-on-shipping-zone/48307672#48307672)"* answer code, to add a shipping zone, however it didn't seem to work in my case.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you forgot to write the hyperlinks for references.

Comment: Please don't add existing code from Stack Overflow in your question if you don't make changes to it… Always add the code snippets links that you have used in your question (even if you have made some changes). Also try to clarify your question editing it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for a specific product category in the order, you will need to loop through the items in the order and check each item for the category you want. Here is your function, modified, followed by a second function that does the work of checking to see if a particular product category is present.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );

function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

  if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

    if ( 'cod' == $order->payment_method ){
      // cash on delivery method
      echo '<p><strong>Please note: </strong>Your repair is currently pending acceptance from your local technician. A member of our team will contact you shortly.</p>';
    }
    else if( is_category_in_order($order, 'unlocking') ){
        // unlocking email
        echo '<p>Your device should be unlocked within 48 hours, if your device requires an unlock code we will be in touch.</p>';
    }
    else {
      // other methods (ie credit card)
      echo '<p><strong>Instructions:</strong> Please ensure your device is packaged securely and send it to the following address:</p><br><br><p><strong>Please note; if using our Unlocking service, you do NOT need to send us your device.</strong></p>';
    }
  }
}

/* Check if order contains a product from a specific category */

function is_category_in_order($order, $target_category) {
      // initialize variable for if category exists in order
    $category_present = false;
      // get the items array from the order object
    $items = $order->get_items();

      // loop through the items in the order
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
          // get the product ID of the current item
        $pid = $item->get_product_id();

          // check if product has target category
        if ( has_term( $target_category, 'product_cat', $pid ) ) {
              // if so, set our category exists in order variable to true
            $category_present = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $category_present;
}
```

[Source of 2nd function & more info](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-check-product-category-order/)

Comment: Amazing, this has fixed the issue and the explainations are certainly helping me learn here.